# Show that if S is a subset of a vector space V, and W is a subset of V where $W \supset S$, then $W \supset Span(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**QUESTION**

Show that if S is a subset of a vector space V, and W is a subset of V where W ⊃ S, then W ⊃ Span(S)

**SOLN**

Lemma:
So we have S ⊆ V, W ⊆ V where W ⊃ S, then its easy to prove that Span(W) ⊃ Span(S) because span of W is a linear combination, and every linear combination of vectors of W lies in W.
Thus, Span(W) ⊂ W.
Similarly, Span(S) ⊂ S

Where do I go from here and eventually prove that W ⊃ Span(S)?

Comment: Seeing the naming, $W$ is probably supposed to be a subspace of $V$ rather than just a subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your claim isn't true. Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$,  $W=[-1,1]\times[-1,1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S=\{(1,1)\}$. Clearly $S\subseteq W$ but $\text{span}(S)\not\subseteq W$. Geometrically, $\text{span}(S)$ is a straight line through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$W\supset  spanW \implies W$ is a subspace...  So it's not true in general...